# How to add approval workflow on Atlassian Bamboo Plan?

Tags: python, bamboo, bitbucket-server, bamboo-specs, bamboo-artifacts

I'm deploying a Bamboo plan with 4 different stages.
The first stage detects whether trigger arrives from either DEV or PROD environments.
If env is DEV, plan can run without problems.
If env is PROD, I would need an approval step after first stage that pauses the plan build, sends a notification to admins and awaits for their approval.

How can I add this feature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Environment permissions is the only way to go as in admins only have access to deploy to PROD. The 4-eyes approval flow you describe is not supported.